# Meaning of "within 10 days from when they move"

Tags: prepositions

> must notify this office of their change of address, within 10 days
>   from when they move

Does this mean I need to let them know of my address change before or after I move out?

Comment: From the time you changed, but if you know it beforehand you may inform them earlier as well.

Comment: But be careful not to notify 11 days before you move; according to the letter it is then disqualified, and presumably you go direct to jail and do not collect £200 :)

Comment: @TimLymington I'll draw your attention to "Monopoly Electronic Banking Edition" complete with credit cards and adjusted for inflation and increased national debt. Pretty soon the board game will be so realistic as to include crack peddlers on each corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context,

> [**From:**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from) indicating the point in time at which a particular process, event or activity ***starts***
>
> - The show will run from 10 am to 2 pm.

So, you need to let them know of your address change within 10 days *after* you change it. (Although, as Em1 said, if you know about it beforehand, there is no harm in letting them know earlier.)

Comment: How can we be sure it's not the undirected 'separation from a salient point in space or time' usage of 'from'?

Answer (score 2):

It's poor grammar and it seems that it could actually be either as it could mean 10 days from (as in before) the move date or 10 days from (as in since) the move date, but common sense says it probably means "10 days AFTER the date you move" as this probably makes the most sense anyway - folks might not know their address until after they move, if they are still finding a place.  You can't make "knowledge of future residence" a requirement of anything like deposit, etc. so it may not "mean" much - are they going to take you to court otherwise?