# A period of at least thirty (30) continuous days from the date

Tags: prepositions, business-language

One of the conditions in a contract is mentioning:

> The hydro power plants to be built to have been completed, commissioned, in operation and successfully generating power for a period of at least thirty (30) continuous days from the date of completion of the Proposed Acquisition.

Is the period mentioned referring to the period before or after the date of the completion of Proposed Acquisition?

To my understanding based on the sentence, the period here is referring to the period after the date of completion of the proposal. But overall it give me a sense that the period is referring to the period before completion date of the proposal.

Comment: After. It says "30 days **from** the date of ..."

Comment: @user431747 Which part of the text gives you the sense that *from* relates to a period prior to its reference date?

Comment: I'd say a duplicate of [meaning of 'within 10 days from when they move'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71750/meaning-of-within-10-days-from-when-they-move), but the answers there are inadequately supported and conflict.

Comment: Also the “to be built to have been completed…” seems wrong.